# Doctrine - Warning message on production server

Tags: php, linux, permissions, doctrine-orm

I'm not able to determine what is causing this, I know its a long shot - but does anyone know what this error might mean? It works perfectly fine on my localhost.

> Warning:
>   file_put_contents(/tmp/NinjaspinCoreEntitiesTemplateProxy.php)
>   [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: Permission denied
>   in
>   /var/www/vhosts/quickbrownfox.in/httpdocs/ninja/vendor/Doctrine/ORM/Proxy/ProxyFactory.php
>   on line 155

I've tried setting all the required write permissions for the entire directory, but I'm still getting this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know i'm way out of date to answer this. but i had exactly the same problem and had no idea why either, permissions and everything was ok.

Then i realized i was setting the option to auto-generate proxies to **true** on my `application.ini` under production settings. (I'm using Doctrine 2.1 with Zend and Bisna)

This causes Doctrine to regenerate proxies en EACH REQUEST, so it was trying to overwrite the existing proxies with new ones, and trying to read them at the same time, or something like that. it's kinda crazy but that's how it's meant to work (auto-generating proxies is something that should only be done in development, anyway)

hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

I also read [here](http://groups.google.com/group/doctrine-user/browse_thread/thread/3c1f7cf6d0979a1a?pli=1) that being in development mode turns this on by default.

Comment: This was what was happening! I fixed it by specifying the directory and by setting development mode off

Answer (score 0):

It seems your `/tmp` directory does not have the correct permission.

In a standard distribution, the default permission of this directory is `rwx rwx rwt`. If you fix this permission like describes below, you won't have any problem any more.

`sudo chmod 1777 /tmp`

Comment: I've given full permissions (777) to the entire directory, and everything inside it.. im still getting this warning.. I dont understand where this directory is

Comment: Are you sure, the sticky bit is activated ? When you set 777 permission, the sticky bit is not activated...